# How to perform/program automatic server health check?

Tags: c#, automation, scheduled-tasks, health-monitoring

We need a way to automatically do some health metrics on a server based on following items:

1. Check if 2-3 of given windows services are alive?
2. Check if a webservice is working ?
3. Restart few windows services
4. Checks a folder for a particular folder. If it does exist - delete them
5. Send out an email if passed .
6. Send a message to mobile if failed.
7. Run all above at a particular time

6.) is not a necessity

From what I analyzed. 
wmic commands can be used for checking restarting  services?
C# based solution to build windows service that can run at a particular time?
C# code for folder checking/deleting
c# to send emails
No Idea for SMS

Are these programing choice/designs will work?

I cannot buy a software piece.. so need a simple solution

Comment: I wrote a C# windows service application that does all of this myself. Works great!
I will try to add more details when I can answer it myself

Answer (score 1):

Checkout metrics.net which can handle health checks;

https://github.com/etishor/Metrics.NET/wiki/Health-Checks

Answer (score 0):

We have similar system in place which its setup is more or less similar to what you have and you really don't need to buy any component to perform these health checks. If I have more information I might be able to give you an already-working code.